# socket communication between NATIVE and AIR app

Tags: java, android, actionscript-3, sockets, air

I'm new to Socket programming and nothing working for me.

```
1. I've an android native app (APP1)
2. I've an AIR for android app (APP2)
```

I'm launching `APP2` from `APP1` using Intent. and when `APP2` is closed I want to send some data to `APP1`.
I want to make `APP1` as a server and `APP2` as client. I want to send and receive data from both apps. I was trying Socket but Its not working. I tried creating normal Java Class (Server) file and AIR app (Client) and I'm running the java in command prompt, and AIR app in Adobe Flash Professional CS6, I'm using `localhost` and port `6000` in AIR app and port `6000` in Java Class and Its working fine. I'm able to send and receive data from Server and Client.
But while applying it in android app, nothing works. I want to run my apps in same device, i.e sending and receiving data in the same device. Can anyone help me please...

**EDIT 1:**
`ServerChat.java`

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class ServerChat implements Runnable
{
    ServerSocket ser;
    Socket s;
    String msg;
    BufferedReader br1,br2;
    PrintWriter pw;
    Thread t1=null,t2=null;
    public ServerChat()
    {
        System.out.println("Server Running...");
        try
        {   
            ser=new ServerSocket(6000);
            System.out.println("Socket Created");
            s=ser.accept();
            System.out.println("accepted");
            br1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            br2=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            pw=new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {}
    }
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            do
            {
                if(Thread.currentThread()==t1)
                {
                    System.out.print("\nServer:");
                    msg=br1.readLine();
                    pw.println(msg);
                }
                else
                {
                    msg=br2.readLine();
                    System.out.println("Client:"+msg);}
            }   
            while(!msg.equals("Q"));
            ser.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {}
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ServerChat ser2=new ServerChat();
        ser2.t1=new Thread(ser2);
        ser2.t2=new Thread(ser2);
        ser2.t1.start();
        ser2.t2.start();
    }
}
```

`ClientChat.java`

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class ClientChat implements Runnable
{

        Socket s;
        String msg;
        BufferedReader br1,br2;
        PrintWriter pw;
        Thread t1=null,t2=null;
        public ClientChat()
        {
            System.out.println("Client Started...");
            try
            {
                s=new Socket("localhost",6000);
                br1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                br2=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                pw=new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {}
        }
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                do
                {
                    if(Thread.currentThread()==t1)
                    {
                        msg=br1.readLine();
                        pw.println(msg);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        msg=br2.readLine();
                        System.out.println(msg);
                    }
                }   
                while(!msg.equals("Q"));
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {}
        }
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            ClientChat c=new ClientChat();
            c.t1=new Thread(c);
            c.t2=new Thread(c);
            c.t1.start();
            c.t2.start();
        }
}
```

I Just Copied these code and paste it in a notepad and saved it as .java, I compiled and run it in 2 different command prompt as `javac ServerChat.java` then `java ServerChat` in first cmd prompt same way for clientChat in second cmd prompt. It works fine.
I kept the Server as it is i.e, `ServerChat.java` and I created an AIR app in Adobe Flash Professional CS6 and just add one text box and a one button with name `_data` and `_send` respectively, I created two .as file named `CustomSocket.as` and `SocketExample.as` and paste the following code in it. Then run the `ServerChat.java` and the AIR app by pressing `CTRL+ENTER` I'm able to send and receive data from java server to AIR client.
`please help me to implement my ServerChat.java in my android App` and `whether localhost works if we run it in actual android device`
`CustomSocket.as`

```
package {
    import flash.errors.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.net.Socket;

    class CustomSocket extends Socket {
        private var response:String;

        public function CustomSocket(host:String = null, port:uint = 0) {
            super();
            configureListeners();
            if (host && port)  {
                super.connect(host, port);
            }
        }

        private function configureListeners():void {
            addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, closeHandler);
            addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, connectHandler);
            addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
            addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
            addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, socketDataHandler);
        }

        public function writeln(str:String):void {
            str += "\n";
            try {
                writeUTFBytes(str);
                trace("wrote");
                flush();
            }
            catch(e:IOError) {
                trace(e);
            }
        }

        private function sendRequest():void {
            trace("sendRequest");
            response = "";
            writeln("GET /");        
        }

        private function readResponse():void {
            var str:String = readUTFBytes(bytesAvailable);
            response += str;
            trace("Response:"+response);
        }

        private function closeHandler(event:Event):void {
            trace("closeHandler: " + event);
            trace(response.toString());
        }

        private function connectHandler(event:Event):void {
            trace("connectHandler: " + event);
            sendRequest();
        }

        private function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
            trace("ioErrorHandler: " + event);
        }

        private function securityErrorHandler(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void {
            trace("securityErrorHandler: " + event);
        }

        private function socketDataHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void {
            trace("socketDataHandler: " + event);
            readResponse();
        }
    }
}
```

`SocketExample.as`

```
package{
    import flash.display.MovieClip; 
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class SocketExample extends MovieClip {
        private var socket:CustomSocket;

        public function SocketExample() {
            socket = new CustomSocket("localhost", 6000);
            _send.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sendNow);
        }
        public function sendNow(e:Event):void{
            trace("data:"+_data.text);
            socket.writeln("Client-"+_data.text);
            trace("sent");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: When you tested with a Java client, did you make it a separate app or in the same app as the server?  I wonder if the server app is still running in the background.  Maybe you could try: 1) a separate client app, and 2) test the AIR client app against the server running on a desktop.

Comment: @Jeff Ward, I've included all my code above. i.e `ServerChat.java` and `ClientChat.java` I'm running these java files in command prompt and its working fine. I've also Included `AIR APP code` i.e `CustomSocket.as` and `SocketExample.as` I'm able to send and receive data from `ServerChat.java` to my air app, How can I implement my above `ServerChat.java` in an Android activity? And if we give `localhost` in client whether it works fine if we run on actual android device?